# How to calculate Lebesgue Outer Measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory

I am having some trouble on the steps I need to follow to calculate Lebesgue measure of some simple sets. For example, I am working on these two examples:

$$1. \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=x^2\}\cap([0,1]\times\mathbb{R}])$$
$$2. \{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$$

I have to prove that the Lebesgue outer measure of both sets is zero. I would like help on how to proceed in these cases (and maybe some general procedure, if there is so).

For the first one I'm thinking about using compactness as an argument, because I can find a finite cover. What could be a suitable one? Probably one with measure $\epsilon$, right?

I don't know what to do for the second example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, your intuition is right. For a more formal argument, consider, for every $k\in\mathbb N$ a cover of the first set by squares of side $1/k$ and centered on $(j/4k,(j/4k)^2)$ for $j\in \{0,...,4k\}$. You can check that the first set is included in one such cover. The area of each square is $1/k^2$ and there are $4k+1$ such squares. The sum of the areas is similar to $4/k$, which goes to zero.

For the second one, one idea is to use the fact that the outer measure is countably subadditive. For instance, you can prove that, for any $m\in\mathbb Z$, the outer measure of $[m,m+1]\times \{0\}$ is 0. Using $\mathbb R\times\{0\}=\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb Z}[m,m+1]\times\{0\}$ and the countable subadditivity of the outer measure you can conclude the outer measure of $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ is zero.

Comment: the second is now clear. for the first I have the idea but I can't find such a cover. Can you help me on that?

Comment: @dic Yes. I have edited my answer for the first case, giving one such possible cover.